# Change backgroud color of the iOS VKB toolbar

Tags: codenameone

I can customize the iOS VKB Toolbar appareance using the `Display.getInstance().setProperty("ios.doneButtonColor", String.valueOf(0xff4500));` to change the "Done" button color and the "done" key in the language bundle to localize the text.

But how can I change the background color of the Toolbar?

For example, this is the current appareance:

[image]

but I prefer a lighter color, as in the following modified image:

[image]

Comment: This isn't supported. Only the foreground color is passed to `Java_com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_editStringAtImpl` and the color of the toolbar is the default color as far as I can tell.